# Saving Joomla front end test scores to the server

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

In a Joomla website I'm working on, the user does an English word knowledge test. The score on this test is calculated by some jQuery code and displayed on the test page. I want to save this score on the front end to the server as part of the user data stored there. I would like the score to be saved automatically on completion of the test. I understand that a php script will be necessary but I was wondering how a script might be triggered by jQuery. I have also looked at the SO articles "saving data from joomla frontend" and "Run php file through jquery link click". These are helpful  but are there any tutorials on php scripting within the Joomla environment? I've checked the Joomla documentation but this seems to be largely oriented towards plugin development. Any help would be much appreciated  Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: When you say "plugin development" do you mean extension development? In Joomla plugin has a specific meaning as a type of extension.   Yes, you possibly do need to develop a Joomla extension but you might just as well install a form extension and have a lot of that work already done for you.   I guess my question is what is it that you are using to produce the form? How are you displaying it? Where do you want to save it?

Comment: The dialog/form which displays the test results on the page as the user proceeds thru the test, is generated by html and the test results inserted into the dialog/form by jQuery code responding to button clicks. This part works OK. I thought that a plugin might be the way to go, given that they are associated with trigger events, (like button clicks?). Anyhow, what I  need is for these user test results to be  saved as part of the user record. Website is english2theworld.com  please check  courses>word set tests 1-15 > the word set tests, Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't save it  in "the user record" you need to figure out where you want to save it. Would it be done as part of editing or creating the profile? In that case you could do it as a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create PHP script to store score to DB

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '/home/snehapur/snehyog');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
/* Create the Application */
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$task = JRequest::getVar('task');
if($task == 'savescore') {
   $userId = JRequest::getVar('userId');
   $score = JRequest::getVar('score');
   // php code to save score in DB
}
?>
```

2) Call PHP Script from jQuery

```
jQuery.get( "myPhpScript.php?task=savescore&userId=123", function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for delay in replying. I'm running a staging copy on the server so I'm guessing but is the value of JPATH_BASE "/home/staging/3"

Comment: Just another question, in what folder should the PHP script placed?

Comment: JPATH_BASE is the path where joomla is installed. I usually put custom php scripts in a separate directoty